# Open a page when Mulitple Options Selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple select box in Html, I need to validate the options select then open a new page taking me to a page where the teacher's profile and the school selected, I need to create a page for each possible answer.

Select Teacher to Study with and School

```
<select id="school">
    <option value="Once" selected="">One</option>
    <option value="Twice">Two</option>
    <option value="Three">Three</option>
    <option value="Four">Four</option>
</select>

<select id="teacher">
    <option value="Once" selected="">Sam</option>
    <option value="Twice">Micheal</option>
    <option value="Three">Manny</option>
    <option value="Four">Jenny</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what will the new page url look like? is it something like /myapp/<school-name>/<teacher-name>

Answer (score 4):

Use this with jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $('#school, #teacher').change(function() {
        //You can validate here if you want
        var myWindow = window.open("http://yourserver.com/myapp/" + $("#school").val() + "/" + $("#teacher").val(), "MsgWindow", "width=800, height=600");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a onchnge event 
HTML:

```
 <select id="school">
<option value="Once" selected=""  onchange="toggle();">One</option>
                        <option value="Twice">Two</option>
                        <option value="Three">Three</option>
                        <option value="Four">Four</option>
                    </select>

 <select id="teacher">
<option value="Once" selected=""  onchange="toggle();">Sam</option>
                        <option value="Twice">Micheal</option>
                        <option value="Three">Manny</option>
                        <option value="Four">Jenny</option>
                    </select>
```

JS:

```
 function toggle(){
            // to do : your logic goes here 
            // redirect to new page 

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use better approach

```
var url = "http://yourserver.com/myapp/";
$(function() {
    $('#school, #teacher').on("change",function() {
        window.open( url + $("#school").val() + "/" + $("#teacher").val());
    });
});
```